# cocos 2dx Display Occasional Get Distorted

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am making a game on cocos2dx for android, and encountering a problem that I was trying to fix for a couple of month without any result:
- all the background and UI shrinked down and flipped, while all the characters (Spine animation stayed normal.
- the problem is not always appears, just occasionally.
Please check out the image for more details (my English is not very good):
[cocos display problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iL4t.jpg)
Have anyone encounter similar problem? I would appreciate any solution pr suggestion.
Thank you very much.

Comment: At a guess I would say that you have a Node* somwhere that is being autoreleased, the memory just happens to be populated with a pointer to the background node so that when you change the properties of the collected node the background is what gets altered.

Comment: Can you specify when this is happening? Just after game starts? Or for some time it's good? Do you have to do something to make this issue to appear? Like powering off screen, returning back to app after pressing home button. If it's just like @ChrisBecke said you can test it running it on desktop, because it shouldn't happen there.

Comment: The issue does not happen all the time, currently I have not find a consistent way to reproduce it, which cause me endless headache.
It never happen when I run the game on PC, it happens when I go to the battle scene and just let the heroes fight each other.

Comment: I found it happen particular often in Samsung Note 2 and LG Phones, and when I was using a Shader to dim the screen.

Comment: So it could be a problem with your shader. It's very likely. Just running cocos2d-x tests on different devices is showing how troublesome shaders may be.

Comment: the problems is, when I have shader on, it happens more often, but when I have shader off, it still happens, so I reckon it must be something else :(

Comment: Then It'd be very hard to guess where the issue come from unless someone had the same problem. If It'd be me, I'd make empty project, copy basic stuff piece by piece and test if problem appears (assuming that I failed finding a method for reproduce it on current project) starting from most suspicious stuff.

Comment: I think you are not using any resolution policy for game.
And check for screen orientation in androidmainfest.xml file